# jQuery form doesn't send

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, send

I have this weird situation where my form doesn't send any data, but the page (which should only be displayed when the data is send) is shown.

I have this code now:

```
     [..]
     if(form == true){
      var gender = $("input[@name='rgender']:checked").val();
      var data = "name="+$("#name").val()+"&gender="+gender+"&country="+$("#country").val()+"&address="+$("#address").val()+"&zip="+$("#zip").val()+"&city="+$("#city").val()+"&mail="+$("#mail").val()+"&phone="+$("#phone").val()+"&checkin="+$("#checkin").val()+"&guests="+$("#guests").val()+"&time="+$("#time").val()+"&nights="+$("#nights").val()+"&remarks="+$("#remarks").val();
      $.ajax({
       url: "http://www.domain.nl/tmp/process.php", 
       type: "GET",    
       data: data,       
       cache: false,
       success: function(){
        $("#content").empty();
        $("#content").load('http://www.domain.nl/tmp/process.php');
       }
      });
      f.preventDefault();
     }
     [..]
```

I checked the data string with an `alert()` before and that one is working well

My php file looks like this, but I don't get any values

`<?php
echo("GET: ".$_GET['name']);
?>`

Comment: Are you doing a GET on a remote domain?  If that's the case your response will be empty due to the same origin policy.

Comment: No it's on the same server/domain, but if i use ../../process.php nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will help:

```
   success: function(result){
    $("#content").html(result);
   }
```

In your code you are sending 2 ajax request. First with $.ajax and with some GET parameters, and second with $().load, but without any parameters.
So actually you can simplify your code to this:

```
if(form == true){
   var gender = $("input[@name='rgender']:checked").val();
   var data = "name="+$("#name").val()+"&gender="+gender+"&country="+$("#country").val()+"&address="+$("#address").val()+"&zip="+$("#zip").val()+"&city="+$("#city").val()+"&mail="+$("#mail").val()+"&phone="+$("#phone").val()+"&checkin="+$("#checkin").val()+"&guests="+$("#guests").val()+"&time="+$("#time").val()+"&nights="+$("#nights").val()+"&remarks="+$("#remarks").val();
   $("#content").load('http://www.cherrytrees.nl/tmp/process.php', data);
   f.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, because i get the following output: <em>GET:<em> Just as it is empty

Comment: it is the problem :) i've edited my post with some explanation

Comment: Hmm.. i tried your solution, but i'm still getting empty values..
process.php loads, but there is no data in it

Comment: oh sorry, i made a mistake in first code snippet. there should be $("#content").html(result);. try changing your success: function to the one i've posted.

Comment: Ok, maybe i'm retarded but those two options both don't work here :( The second one actually sends my form (so preventDefault) somehow don't work and the first one still gives me no data (allthough process.php loads)

Comment: try alert($("#name").val()); are you sure it's not empty?

Comment: I'm sorry, IT WORKS!! You're my hero!! I still used the GET method, but i changed it to POST en everything is allright! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change it as follows:

```
url: "http://www.cherrytrees.nl/tmp/process.php?" + data,
```

In your original request you were sending it via POST, rather than GET.

Comment: its sending via GET... `type: "GET"`

Comment: i've just tested same ajax request - it works for me. so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 url: "http://www.cherrytrees.nl/tmp/process.php", 
       type: "GET",    
       data: data,
```

the option "data" ist only for POST type, if you wont to GET paratmeeters, write them in your URL

```
url.com?name="+$("#name").val()+"&gende....
```

Comment: read my comment to xil3 post. I think Nick Craver posted right asnwer in OP post's comments.